# What is the proper usage of asynchronoscity in an Angular app with injected service?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to implement the ability to delete a specific document in a firebase collection, as a button in a component. To do this, I'm using an Angular service to get all the document IDs in a collection, as shown below (because the IDs also have utility in other components):

```
getCurrUserDocID(){ 
      this.getUsers().subscribe(arr =>{
         this.listUsers = arr.map(item => {
           return{
            userDocID : item.payload.doc.id,
            ...item.payload.doc.data() as User
           }
        })
      }) 

      return{        
        userIDs : this.listUsers
      };
```

Injecting this service into components *does* allow me to get the docIDs. However, it's finicky. When I called it in ngOnInit in a component that loads under a navbar tab, it doesn't work unless I click that tab a couple times:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.service.getCurrUserDocID().userIDs)
  }
```

The first and second click return an empty array in the console, while the third finally returns the actual array of data. I suspect this has something to do with observables and asychronous-ity.

Comment: You can approve my Edit of your question and check what i did in there so in future you will know how to correct style code.

Comment: Remember: "your service return observables, you subscribe in components"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a subscription to get the data from `this.getUsers()` observer.
On getting new data you set the value of `this.listUsers`.
Now all you need in your component is to access this.listUsers.

Just remember that every time there will be data coming from `this.getUsers()` observer the value of `this.listUsers` will be overwritten which will cause your component to rerender.

The fact you get the data only on the third invocation may be related to the time it takes for `this.getUsers()` to return date or to the way you use it.
You have to notice that the subscription to the observable will return multiple results.

Comment: Thank you! I changed `this.service.getCurrUserDocID().userIDs` to `this.service.listUsers` and the console prints the proper data on the first try. To clarify: Instead of calling the service, then subscribing to the firestore collection and actively updating the value with each console log (because its an active subscription), the new code calls the property of the service, list users, which is already populated after the initial subscription (i.e. it wouldn't continually update) -- right?

Comment: If you want to get the data only once you can use it like that but you should unsubscribe (you can use pipe and inside of it `take(1)` which will unsubscribe from the observer)

Comment: as you said, the data is overwritten because of the time it takes to get it. How do you implement functionality that only returns a list after all the data from a collection is gotten? Is an observer still the right thing to use? Is this the use-case for await?

Comment: If you want to get the data only once from the observer you can just add the `service.listUsers.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data=>)` this will make sure the observer is unsubscribe after getting all the data.
If you wish to get updates to the data then don't unsubscribe.
Await are for promises and you are dealing with observable here

Answer (score 1):

Don't subscribe out of component becouse you will need to unsubscribe it. If you want to sort data use `map()` operator in `pipe()`.

```js
getCurrUserDocID(){
    this.listUsers = this.getUsers().pipe(
        map(item => {
            return {
                userDocID: item.payload.doc.id,
                ...item.payload.doc.data() as User
            }
        })
    )
};
```

In component

```js
constructor(public: service: Service) {} // Make it public so you can use it in html file

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getCurrUserDocID() // here just triger `getUsers()` function.
}
```

In html template with async pipe

```html
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of service.listUsers | async">
      {{item.id}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Async pipe in template are subscribing and unsubscribing for you so you no need to worry about data leaks.